# What is the best book with american typography rules?

Tags: formatting, typography, books

There is russian book [Reference book of editor and author](http://www.artlebedev.com/everything/izdal/spravochnik-izdatelya-i-avtora-2014/) which is well-known and considered the best comprehensive guide to typography and writing of text in russian (formatting, margins, font sizes and so on). You can get the idea if you peek my link (even everything is in Russian).

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic since there’s no direct connection to TeX & Co. I recommend to migrate this question to [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: Hello? How it is related to graphics design? Is there any community connected closely to typography than TeX?

Comment: Very important question, especially because the (La)TeX rules are not always the same as  national typographic rules.

Comment: @dig We generally welcome typography questions here, as long as they have some **overt** connection to *TeX, which your question lacks. On [graphicdesign.se], `fonts` is the 4th most popular tag, `typography` is no. 8.

Comment: @doncherry But the only reason I am here is that I am seriously concerned *how* I should do things in my LaTex

Comment: @dig You could ask: a) In book xyz on typography I read that I should do X. How do I do that with LaTeX? or b) What’s a good guide on how to implement American typography in LaTeX? (This one might’ve been asked already.) It’s just that typography in general isn’t particular to LaTeX, just like questions about academic practice in general (How to cite according to style xyz?) are off-topic here, unless they have a overt connection to LaTeX (How to implement citation style xyz in LaTeX? Or better: I can’t get this detail about citation style xyz to work, how do I do that?).

Comment: @doncherry I hope you feel yourself proud defending virginity of this board. And I still have no answers on graphics board (obviously because designers draw in Photoshop and don't prepare texts for printing).